# Scraping td elements with background color style BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, html-table, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse a webpage where i want to scrape "tr" elements which have bgcolor attribute also. Below is the html for the webpage:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="15" id="MainContent_GridView1" style="color:#333333;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr style="color:White;background-color:#045D99;font-weight:bold;">
        <th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$name&#39;)" style="color:White;">ORGANIZATION NAME</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$state&#39;)" style="color:White;">STATE</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$year&#39;)" style="color:White;">YEAR</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$rt&#39;)" style="color:White;">FORM</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$pc&#39;)" style="color:White;">PAGES</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$ta&#39;)" style="color:White;">TOTAL ASSETS</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$ein&#39;)" style="color:White;">EIN</a></th>
    </tr><tr style="color:#333333;background-color:#ECEEF2;">
        <td><a href="//990s.foundationcenter.org/990_pdf_archive/231/231352298/231352298_201702_990.pdf">Zoological Society of Philadelphia Philadelphia Zoo</a></td><td>PA</td><td>2017</td><td>990   </td><td align="right">68</td><td align="right">$124,163,973.00</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;">23-1352298</td>
    </tr><tr style="color:#333333;background-color:White;">
        <td><a href="//990s.foundationcenter.org/990_pdf_archive/231/231352298/231352298_201602_990.pdf">Zoological Society of Philadelphia</a></td><td>PA</td><td>2016</td><td>990   </td><td align="right">61</td><td align="right">$125,008,026.00</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;">23-1352298</td>
    </tr><tr style="color:#333333;background-color:#ECEEF2;">
        <td><a href="//990s.foundationcenter.org/990_pdf_archive/231/231352298/231352298_201502_990.pdf">Zoological Society of Philadelphia</a></td><td>PA</td><td>2015</td><td>990   </td><td align="right">63</td><td align="right">$131,880,929.00</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;">23-1352298</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to scrape tr elements using style element

```
style="color:White;background-color:#045D99;font-weight:bold;"
```

Below is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,"lxml")
elems = soup.find_all('tr',style"color:White;background-color:#045D99;font-weight:bold;")
```

However my elems returns empty. Also in my soup element, i see that:

```
style="color:White;background-color:#045D99;font-weight:bold;"
```

has changed to

```
<tr bgcolor="#ECEEF2">
```

I am not sure if this is causing the problem, also is there a way to scrape the whole tables as a pandas dataframe instead?

Edit:

I had a typo in my code, below is the correct code:

```
soup.find_all('tr',{"style":"color:White;background-color:#045D99;font-weight:bold;"})
```

Same as mentioned in the answers, still i get null results

One more Edit:

Even after the suggestions, i am still getting null results. The html is from below webpage:

```
http://990finder.foundationcenter.org/990results.aspx?990_type=&fn=AMERICAN+HEART+ASSOCIATION&st=&zp=&ei=&fy=&action=Search
```

I am trying to parse the table present in the webpage

Comment: What output do you expect?

Answer (score 1):

I will take you fairly literally. The `background-color` is not an attribute but part of the `style` attribute value. Assuming you want one containing that substring (and to cater for different colours perhaps), we can use contains, *, operator to match on `style` attribute value

```
html = '''<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="15" id="MainContent_GridView1" style="color:#333333;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr style="color:White;background-color:#045D99;font-weight:bold;">
        <th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$name&#39;)" style="color:White;">ORGANIZATION NAME</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$state&#39;)" style="color:White;">STATE</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$year&#39;)" style="color:White;">YEAR</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$rt&#39;)" style="color:White;">FORM</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$pc&#39;)" style="color:White;">PAGES</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$ta&#39;)" style="color:White;">TOTAL ASSETS</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$ein&#39;)" style="color:White;">EIN</a></th>
    </tr><tr style="color:#333333;background-color:#ECEEF2;">
        <td><a href="//990s.foundationcenter.org/990_pdf_archive/231/231352298/231352298_201702_990.pdf">Zoological Society of Philadelphia Philadelphia Zoo</a></td><td>PA</td><td>2017</td><td>990   </td><td align="right">68</td><td align="right">$124,163,973.00</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;">23-1352298</td>
    </tr><tr style="color:#333333;background-color:White;">
        <td><a href="//990s.foundationcenter.org/990_pdf_archive/231/231352298/231352298_201602_990.pdf">Zoological Society of Philadelphia</a></td><td>PA</td><td>2016</td><td>990   </td><td align="right">61</td><td align="right">$125,008,026.00</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;">23-1352298</td>
    </tr><tr style="color:#333333;background-color:#ECEEF2;">
        <td><a href="//990s.foundationcenter.org/990_pdf_archive/231/231352298/231352298_201502_990.pdf">Zoological Society of Philadelphia</a></td><td>PA</td><td>2015</td><td>990   </td><td align="right">63</td><td align="right">$131,880,929.00</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;">23-1352298</td>
    </tr>
</table>'''


import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
soup = bs(html,"lxml")
trs = soup.select('tr[style*=";background-color:"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing last line of your code:

```
soup.find_all('tr',{"style":"color:White;background-color:#045D99;font-weight:bold;"})
```

you get:

```
[<tr style="color:White;background-color:#045D99;font-weight:bold;">
 <th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$GridView1','Sort$name')" style="color:White;">ORGANIZATION NAME</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$GridView1','Sort$state')" style="color:White;">STATE</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$GridView1','Sort$year')" style="color:White;">YEAR</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$GridView1','Sort$rt')" style="color:White;">FORM</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$GridView1','Sort$pc')" style="color:White;">PAGES</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$GridView1','Sort$ta')" style="color:White;">TOTAL ASSETS</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$GridView1','Sort$ein')" style="color:White;">EIN</a></th>
 </tr>]
```

---

Concerning your last question, assuming `t` stores the html of the table of interest, you can convert it into a `DataFrame` by using [`pandas.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html(t)

display(df[0])
```

In your case, you get:

```
                  ORGANIZATION NAME   STATE YEAR    FORM PAGES  TOTAL ASSETS       EIN
0   Zoological Society of Philadelphia  PA  2017    990    68   $124,163,973.00 23-1352298
1   Zoological Society of Philadelphia  PA  2016    990    61   $125,008,026.00 23-1352298
2   Zoological Society of Philadelphia  PA  2015    990    63   $131,880,929.00 23-1352298
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is off. Change to this:

```
elems = soup.find_all('tr', {"style":"color:White;background-color:#045D99;font-weight:bold;"})
```

**Full Code:**

```
data = '''<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="15" id="MainContent_GridView1" style="color:#333333;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr style="color:White;background-color:#045D99;font-weight:bold;">
        <th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$name&#39;)" style="color:White;">ORGANIZATION NAME</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$state&#39;)" style="color:White;">STATE</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$year&#39;)" style="color:White;">YEAR</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$rt&#39;)" style="color:White;">FORM</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$pc&#39;)" style="color:White;">PAGES</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$ta&#39;)" style="color:White;">TOTAL ASSETS</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$ein&#39;)" style="color:White;">EIN</a></th>
    </tr><tr style="color:#333333;background-color:#ECEEF2;">
        <td><a href="//990s.foundationcenter.org/990_pdf_archive/231/231352298/231352298_201702_990.pdf">Zoological Society of Philadelphia Philadelphia Zoo</a></td><td>PA</td><td>2017</td><td>990   </td><td align="right">68</td><td align="right">$124,163,973.00</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;">23-1352298</td>
    </tr><tr style="color:#333333;background-color:White;">
        <td><a href="//990s.foundationcenter.org/990_pdf_archive/231/231352298/231352298_201602_990.pdf">Zoological Society of Philadelphia</a></td><td>PA</td><td>2016</td><td>990   </td><td align="right">61</td><td align="right">$125,008,026.00</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;">23-1352298</td>
    </tr><tr style="color:#333333;background-color:#ECEEF2;">
        <td><a href="//990s.foundationcenter.org/990_pdf_archive/231/231352298/231352298_201502_990.pdf">Zoological Society of Philadelphia</a></td><td>PA</td><td>2015</td><td>990   </td><td align="right">63</td><td align="right">$131,880,929.00</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;">23-1352298</td>
    </tr>
</table>'''


import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#data = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,"lxml")
elems = soup.find_all('tr', {"style":"color:White;background-color:#045D99;font-weight:bold;"})
```